# Javascript Comparing String Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do comparing string because I need to have calculation. The string from select option in HTML and another will be the variable string.

This is my HTML Code:

```
 <label>Freight Cost Mode</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="freightcostmode_insert" name="freightCostMode_insert" onchange="val()">  
 <option>Percentage</option>
 <option>Monetary</option>
 </select> 
 <input class="form-control" id="freightcost_insert" type="text" placeholder="Freight Cost Mode" name="freightCost_insert" onkeyup="val()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="freight">
```

This is my javascript code:

```
        <script>
        function val() {
        var input = document.getElementById("freightcostmode_insert").value;
        var calculation = document.getElementById("freightCost_insert").value;
        if(inputing == "Percentage"){
            document.getElementById('freight').value = calculation*1.5;
        }if else(inputing == 'Monetary'){

        }         

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1):

For first your `inputing` variable does not exist - maybe `input`.

For second parse the `calculation` value into a number.

Also you have some syntax errors in your code.

```js
function val() {
  var input =  document.getElementById("freightcostmode_insert").value;
  var calculation = document.getElementById("freightcost_insert").value;
  
  if(input == "Percentage"){
     document.getElementById('freight').value = parseInt(calculation) * 1.5;
  } else if(input == 'Monetary'){

  }         
}
```

```html
<label>Freight Cost Mode</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="freightcostmode_insert" name="freightCostMode_insert" onchange="val()">  
 <option>Percentage</option>
 <option>Monetary</option>
 </select> 
 <input class="form-control" id="freightcost_insert" type="text" placeholder="Freight Cost Mode" name="freightCost_insert" onkeyup="val()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="freight">
```

Comment: hmm ok i will try and edit it my bad I didn't check XD

Comment: _"Also you have some syntax errors in your code."_ That's a "typo" question. Please close-vote the question as such, then.

Answer (score -1):

Working Code

```js
function val() {
  var input = document.getElementById("freightcostmode_insert").value,
    calculation = document.getElementById("freightcost_insert").value

  document.getElementById('freight').value = input === "Percentage" ?
    calculation * 1.5 : calculation * 2.5;
}
```

```html
<label>Freight Cost Mode</label>
<select class="form-control" id="freightcostmode_insert" name="freightCostMode_insert" onchange="val()">  
   <option>Percentage</option>
   <option>Monetary</option>
 
 </select>

<input class="form-control" id="freightcost_insert" type="text" placeholder="Freight Cost Mode" name="freightCost_insert" onkeyup="val()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="freight">
```